# How do i allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in Node.JS Http Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to send a POST from a client connected to this server to a external URL. I get a lot of 'CORS' errors. Im pretty sure that it's because i haven't allowed 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and etc on my Node.JS server. But i don't know how to do it. I have found another answers on the web, but none of them solved my problem.
Here is my server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const { instrument } = require('@socket.io/admin-ui')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var clientesConectados = [];

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  //send the index.html file for all requests
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

app.post('/', (request, res) => {
  console.log("********************");
  console.log(" >POST RECEBIDO!!");
 console.log(res);
 
postData = request.body;
io.emit('message',postData); 
 console.log(postData);

});



http.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log('listening on *:3000');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Express has a middleware for CORS. [Link here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Answer (score 1):

Install cors package in your application

npm install cors

And then add these two lines in there

```
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors())
```

Else there are ways that set through header or you could use a proxy in your frontend but using cors package is simpler

Answer (score 0):

Install npm package called [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

After installing, on your file add this line `app.use(cors())` will solve your issue of cors error I hope.